# Encoding large video file(200MB+) to base64 in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, base64, oom

Recently, I encountered a confusion which is encoding large video file to base64 in Android.Until I write down the question,haven't solved it yet.
What am I do this because the server requires the client to upload files in this way,
I sought help from `ChatGPT`,But it still cannot solve various problems that arise during the coding process, including OOM(Out of memory Exception..).
What I should do? thanks.

How to resolve and avoid the OOM Exception.

Comment: How to avoid OOM... Don't load the whole file into memory? You can process a file by smaller blocks.

Comment: It’s the first time to encountered this issue , we use  the OkHttp by application/Json header tried many ways but still can't solve it.

Comment: Please post your code for building the HTTP request. BTW: Starting your display user name with a special character makes it difficult to use it in an `@` reply. I would recommend to let it start with ascii characters and move the special characters to the end.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your OutputStream with `Base64OutputStream`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream

Comment: Maybe I'm using it wrong，Using `Base64OutputStream` and still getting OOM 
 by OkHttp application/json

Comment: Maybe. You might have noticed that you haven't posted any code.